# Automating Azure Logic Apps with Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-logic-apps

How can I automate Azure Logic Apps deployment using Ansible? Is there an option other that ARM templates via ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Azure Collection for Ansible](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure) doesn't support Logic Apps, so the ARM Template via Ansible would be the one way for now.

Since its open source, you could always contribute the module if you end up writing your own.